# Can't format print string

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, format

How can one convert the code below from the older/less readable style %s % (value) print to f'{value} newer format method. Is it possible to loop and use the .format in python?

```
data = {'123':'asd','234':'sdf'}
string = ''.join(' %s="%s"' % (key, value) for key,value in data.items())
print(string)
```

Output:

```
123="asd" 234="sdf"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible:

```
>>> data = {'123':'asd','234':'sdf'}
>>> string = ''.join(f' {key}="{value}"' for key,value in data.items())
>>> string
' 123="asd" 234="sdf"'
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want to convert the `%` style string-formatting into newer style of f-strings:

```
print(' '.join(f'{k}="{v}"' for k,v in data.items())
```

Output:

```
'123="asd" 234="sdf"'
```

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, they are equivalent. [Code on repl.it](https://repl.it/@NotAnAmbiTurner/CoralLongtermEquations):

```
data = {'123':'asd','234':'sdf'}

print("-- % --")
string1 = ''.join(' %s="%s"' % (key, value) for key,value in data.items())
print(string1)

print("\n-- .format() --")
string2 = ''.join([' {}="{}"'.format(key, value) for key, value in data.items()])
print(string2)

print("\n-- f'string' --")
string3 = ''.join([f' {key}="{value}"' for key, value in data.items()])
print(string3)
```

Out:

```
-- % --
 123="asd" 234="sdf"

-- .format() --
 123="asd" 234="sdf"

-- f'string' --
 123="asd" 234="sdf"
```